# why is first child of the body undefined?

Tags: javascript

It runs ok on the body but outputs undefined on the first child. 
what am i doing wrong?

```js
    function doit(e) {
      console.log('tag: ' + e.tagName);
      console.log('nt: ' + e.nodeType);
      for (var childElement in e.children) {
        doit(childElement);
      }
    }

    doit(document.body);
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="fork">
    <li id="myli" class="myclass">Hello</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

This helped me finish my css cleaner. Check it out [[jsfiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/toddmo/cojL0ug0/)

Comment: Because one of the elements in the `for-in` loop is going to be the enumerable `length` property of the `HTMLCollection` returned by `document.body.children` (that `length` property is a number which has neither a `tagName` nor a `nodeType` property). That’s why you shouldn’t use a `for-in` loop but a normal `for` loop.

Comment: A text node does not have a tagName.

Comment: You can add `console.log(e)` to inspect what 'e' actually is for each execution.

Comment: @Xufox—not necessarily a reason not to use *for..in* (perhaps the intention is to find all enumerable properties), more a reason to deal with different Types of values that might be returned and not expect them all to be of the same Type (or same kind of object). E.g. a NodeList can contain text nodes, which are DOM objects but don't have a *tagName* property.

Comment: @AnthonyTambrin, what expression would you recommend? All e says is object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for...in` loops iterate enumerable properties, but you want to iterate the values. Then,

```
for (var prop in e.children)
  doit(e.children[prop]);
```

However, that's a bad way of iterating array-like objects. Better use

```
for (var i = 0; i<e.children.length; ++i)
  doit(e.children[i]);
```

Or with ES5 array methods

```
[].forEach.call(e.children, doit);
```

```js
function doit(e) {
  console.log('tag: ' + e.tagName);
  console.log('nt: ' + e.nodeType);
  [].forEach.call(e.children, doit);
}
doit(document.body);
```

```html
<ul id="fork">
  <li id="myli" class="myclass">Hello</li>
</ul>
```